# RubyOnRails self reference many to many

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, self-reference

I've got a Product model and I need to implement related products, so I thought a self reference is the best way to do it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related_product_associations, class_name: "RelatedProduct"
  has_many :related_products, through: :related_product_associations, source: :related_product
end

class RelatedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :related_product, class_name: "Product"
end
```

In products_controller:

```
params.require(:product).permit(..., :related_products, ...)
```

Questions:
 1. Are my models/controller all right
 2. How to make form for several related products.

I thought the forms may look something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :related_product, @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.collection_select :related_product, @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.collection_select :related_product, @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

In products_controller:

```
@products = Product.all
```

3. Is there a way to implement cocoon-like behavior with jQuery nested forms so I can add more fields only if I need them?

Comment: For the naming on the models - I'd consider calling the join table something like related_product_association, since that's what you call it in the product model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is to submit an array of ids in this form `related_product_ids=[1,2,3,4]`.

To do that, the param has to be named product[realted_product_ids][]. Unfortunately, you can't do this.  The second param has to be a param

```
# Note this doesn't work
<%= f.collection_select 'related_product_ids[]', @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

But, you can do this (with multiple)

```
<%= f.collection_select :related_product_ids, @products, :id, :name, {:selected => @product.related_product_ids, :include_blank => true}, {:multiple => true} %>
```

Or you can do this

```
<%- (1..4).each do |i| %>
  <%= select_tag 'product[related_product_ids][]', options_for_select(@products.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, @product.related_product_ids[i]), :include_blank => true %>
<% end %>
```

You can also try it out with check boxes. Later, switching to dropdowns added dynamically shouldn't be too hard.

```
<%- @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'product[related_product_ids][]', product.id, @product.related_product_ids.include?(product.id) %>
  <%= product.name %>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Hello Swards! Thank you for a kind reply.

<%= f.collection_select 'product[related_product_ids][]', @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true %> raises an exception: undefined method `product[related_product_ids][]' for #<Product:0x00000004d45ef0>

I assume you meant product[related_product_ids][] except of related_product_ids[]. Anyway, the original code raises same exception too.

Comment: Check boxes variant works almost like a charm, however. The only problem that related_product_ids don't save to DB, logs say that this is unpermitted parameter despite the fact that I whitelisted it:
params.require(:product).permit(..., :related_product_ids, ...)

Comment: params.require(:product).permit(..., related_product_ids: [], ...)

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly!
Have you got any idea why collection_select raised an exception btw?

Comment: I don't use collection select much, but it seems it should handle multiple correctly.  Try <%= f.collection_select :related_product_ids, @products, :id, :name, include_blank: true, multiple: true %>.  This may send it in an array format.

Comment: I updated answer with some other options for this problem.  I tried out the multiple and the select_tag approach, both worked.  Each comes with tradeoffs.